# How to fix error when .launch() application

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I am writing ui tests for an application. I have a set of 40 test scripts. When I run each test separately, there are no problems. But when I try to run all the tests in a row, I get this error:

```
Failed to create directory on device 'iPhone (o...a)' (1...c) to hold runtime profiles for application with bundle ID '...': No matching application with bundle identifier '...'
Domain: IDEFoundationErrorDomain
Code: 17
--
No matching application with bundle identifier '...'
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
Code: 0
--
```

On completion of each test in `tearDownWithError()` I delete my app. At the beginning of each test in `setUpWithError()` I launch my application using `XCUIApplication().launch()`.
The error occurs after the application tries to run in the second test
`tearDownWithError()` looks like that:

```
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier:"com.apple.springboard")  
XCUIApplication().terminate()springboard.icons["MyApp"].press(forDuration: 3)  
sleep(1)  
springboard.icons["MyApp"].buttons["DeleteButton"].tap()  
sleep(3)  
let deleteapp = springboard.buttons["Удалить приложение"]  
if deleteapp.waitForExistence(timeout: 1){deleteapp.tap()}  
let delete = springboard.buttons["Удалить"]  
if delete.waitForExistence(timeout: 1){delete.tap()}
```

`setUpWithError()` looks like that:

```
continueAfterFailure = false  
XCUIApplication().launch()
```

The specified error occurs at the line `XCUIApplication().launch()`

Comment: Is there a reason you're deleting the app? That's the obvious problem. Err the problem is it not being reinstalled - I would think setUp would reinstall, but I'm not sure where that occurs. If you can get away without deleting the app, I bet that'll solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the end of each test script, I need to delete the application to fully build it. This is necessary for me so that each new test starts with the same "clean" state. Unfortunately, I still do not understand how this can be implemented, given the error given in the question.

Comment: I'm at a loss; launch() should reinstall the app. How exactly are you deleting? How are you referencing the app in setup? Can you share the code in both your setup and teardown functions?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running? There was an issue here that seems to be resolved in Xcode 11.4.

Comment: I added code to the description of the problem. Used version of Xcode 12.4

Comment: Two ideas: 1) What if you wait longer after deleting? Perhaps the OS is still doing something with the uninstall when you try to reinstall? 2) What if you specify your bundle ID in the XCUIApplication("com.myworkplace.myapp").launch()? Perhaps XCUITest thinks it's working with something other than your app since you've interfaced with the Springboard?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. Trying to upgrade to xcode 13...

Comment: Do you have a super.setUp() somewhere in your setup? Pasting complete code is very helpful…